# Ask Different Chat Room

Tags: discussion, chat

We do have [a room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/apple-chat) on the new Stack Exchange chat system for anyone who wants to join. To enter, you must:

- Have at least 20 reputation on Stack Exchange

The room is for discussing anything and everything about our site. Its also a neat place to meet and talk to the people who have been answering your questions, yell at the moderators or just lurk. Hopefully we also discuss things surrounding the site.

[Original text ripped from Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/pro-webmasters-chat-room)

Comment: The chatroom seems to be frozen…

Comment: I don't have the rep to edit, but note that this room has now been migrated to chat.SE

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

## For those who are relatively new to the sites

The link to Ask Different Chat is in the right hand column of Ask Different:

- sometimes visible without scrolling down
- sometimes out of sight (beneath advertisements).

The link to Ask Different Chat is sometimes [**missing** from the right hand column of Ask Different meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/729/8546).

To switch from Ask Different meta to Ask Different:

- click `main`

Alongside `main` for Ask Different, the `chat` is **not** Ask Different Chat.