# Why is the link to Ask Different Chat sometimes missing from Ask Different meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

In [an answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/apple-chat-room/728#728) to **Apple Chat Room**:

> The link to Ask Different Chat is sometimes **missing** from the right hand column of Ask Different meta.

[image]

In the meta page to the left of that screenshot:

- no link.

Reloading the pages does not resolve the inconsistency. I'll upload a movie to the following folder:

- http://www.wuala.com/%23%23Apple-support/members/grahamperrin/2011/08/19/a/

Please, is the randomness by design? Or is there some other explanation?

Whatever the reason: the inconsistency around a key feature is disorienting, smells a little buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sidebar ad will not appear on questions until questions have more than 1 answer.

This is to

- focus on the question
- prevent the sidebar from becoming absurdly tall, much taller than the central area of the page itself

Comment: Is Ask Different Chat classed as advertising? I think of it as a near-essential complement to Ask Different.

Comment: It is classified as a house ad, but the real issue is length of the sidebar